# Apple watch - maps screen stuck

Tags: apple-watch, maps

My apologies if the post is not following the guidelines of the community, but unfortunately googling and looking in other communities has not been helpful with the problem I am facing.

After updating to 13.0 on my iPhone, I used the (apple) maps app in order to guide me to a destination. Since maps were linked to my apple watch, the navigation was forwarded to it.

The problem is that after finishing the navigation, my watch remained stuck on the navigation screen - it pops up instead of the default face screen every time I turn my wrist towards me.

So far, I tried to do the following to remediate to the problem :

- force shut down the maps app on the iPhone
- force shut down the maps app on the watch from the recent apps
- check that the navigation was terminated: It was, the screen asks me
  to choose a location to navigate to
- look for a button to exit the navigation prompt from the maps app on my watch

None of those steps worked.

Is this a known issue? What can be done to address it?

Specific hardware:
iPhone SE; iOS 13.0; Apple Watch S0; WatchOS 4.3.2

Comment: Update your iOS to 13.1 and reboot both devices. that might help it as 13.0 has several bugs.

Comment: A reboot of the watch seemed to do the job; I updated to 13.2 and will check if that solves the issue.